# numpy.array wont let me pass two arguments

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
image_array = np.array(final_image, "uint8")
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with `final_image = [1]`, and the [NumPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) say *dtype* can be a positional argument, with no mention of that ever changing. So please make a [mre] including complete code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). BTW, if you want more tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the keyword argument *dtype*.

```py
import numpy as np 

image_array = np.array(final_image, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  `dtype` as the 2nd positional argument is fine - normally.  Something else is going on.